# SSIS BIML generates SQL code with brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, informix, biml

Im using BIML to dynamically create load packages for SSIS to load data from Informix to SQL Server. The problem is that this BIML code produces the SQL below

```
<DirectInput>SELECT <#=table.GetColumnList()#> FROM <#=table.GetTag("SourceSchemaQualifiedName")#></DirectInput>

SELECT [column1], [column2], [column3], FROM [mySchema].[mySrcTable]
```

But that doesnt work in my source database because of the brackets. Any way i can get the columnlist & tablename without the brackets dynamically?

Comment: Not familiar with BIML & Informix: Is there anything that's preventing you from manually removing the brackets before running the query?

Comment: Well i have almost 700 packages, so its not really an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the overloaded method of [GetColumnList](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Api/Method/AstTableNode/GetColumnList(String%2CString%2CString))

```
<#=table.GetColumnList(string.Empty, "\"", "\"")#>
```

which should produce a double quote wrapped column name with no table alias - which I *think* is what Informix expects.

Answer (score 0):

This works for both column names and table name:

```
                        <OdbcSource Name="Data from informix" Connection="Source_Informix">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT <#=table.GetColumnList(string.Empty, "", "")#> FROM schema.<#=table.Name#></DirectInput>
                        </OdbcSource>
                        <OleDbDestination Name="Data to MSSQL" ConnectionName="Target_MSSQL">
                            <TableOutput TableName="<#=table.ScopedName#>"/>
                        </OleDbDestination>
```